# PHP: Сравнить csv 2 файла

Tags: php

Есть ли какой-то гибкий инструмент для сравнения двух CSV файлов ?
Новые Удаленные строки, изменения в ячейках и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Такой инструмент неизвестен. Можно загрузить csv средствами PHP (например, используя класс [parseCSV](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/)) в базу данных SQL, и уже затем использовать возможности базы данных для анализа. При выборе SQL подход такой

- создать таблицу с такими же столбцами, что и в исходных файлах,
- добавить данные из первого файла,
- построчно сравнить с другими файлами путем чтения строки второго файла и выборки из базы (SELECT).